# Drawing Text to the canvas using three.js

Tags: asp.net-mvc, three.js

To start, I am not the most advanced javascript developer. I have only now started to undertake a more serious study of the subject.

So one of my first forays in this subject is to draw some text to the canvas using the three.js library.But for the life of me, I can't get this sucker to work. I have looked on google and even through the three.js documentation. When I inspect the page in chrome, the page doesn't show any errors either. Here is my code for reference:

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / 
window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ alpha: true });
renderer.setClearColor(0xdddddd);

var spotlight = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff,);
spotlight.castShadow = true;
spotlight.position.set(30,60,60);

renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var loader = new THREE.FontLoader();

loader.load( 'fonts/helvetiker_regular.typeface.json', function ( font ) {

    var textGeo = new THREE.TextGeometry( 'Hello three.js!', {
        font: font,
        size: 80,
        height: 5,
        curveSegments: 12,
        bevelEnabled: true,
        bevelThickness: 10,
        bevelSize: 8,
        bevelSegments: 5
    } );

    var  color = new THREE.Color();
    color.setRGB(255, 250, 250);
    textGeo.computeBoundingBox();
    textGeo.computeVertexNormals();
    var textMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: color });

    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(textGeo, textMaterial);
    mesh.position.x = textGeo.boundingBox.max.x / 2;
    mesh.position.y = textGeo.boundingBox.max.y / 2;
    mesh.castShadow = true; 
    scene.add(mesh); 
} );



var render = function (){
requestAnimationFrame(render);
renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
camera.lookAt(scene.position);
render();
```

Also, for some background if it's needed, I am running this in debug mode in an asp.net application.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: in the given code, what position of your camera?

Answer (score 0):

I had my camera directly on the scene, so I couldn't see anything. Thanks prisoner for comment.